# VB.net redistributable assemblies

Tags: vb.net, redistributable

I have a VB.net project that uses third party assemblies.

In the production side. I have to put the executable with all of this assemblies in the same folder in order for the application to work.

the problem is that I use a lot of assemblies. and I fear that a user deletes some of those assemblies which will cause the application to stop working !

So is it possible to put all those assemblies in any other folder? let's say c:\assemblies ?

Can you please tell me the steps to do it properly under vb.net ?

Comment: Why would a user god deleting those files? Do you lose sleep over the possibility that someone will delete your EXE and stop the program working? Why couldn't someone delete something from 'C:\assemblies'?Everyone's computer is full of applications that are comprised of many different files and the only people deleting critical files from random folders are the ones who shouldn't have a computer in the first place. Worry about real issues.

Comment: I think users are far more likely to arbitrarily delete assemblies that are put in a central location than if they're in the same folder as your program.